# ASP.net MVC Ajax DataTable Error 7

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Kinda newbie when it comes to ASP.net MVC side of things not sure why I am getting Ajax Error 7 in DataTable

here is my code : for cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <title>Register new  Users</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap
    /3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/
    jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
    span.field-validation-error {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div style="width:90%; margin:0 auto ">
    you are in the Table area

    <table id="myDatatable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>User ID</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>User Email</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Users ImagePath</th>
                <th>SSID</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>




<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var oTable = $('#myDatatable').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": '/home/GetUsers',
                "type" : "get",
                "dataType": "json"
            }, 

            "columns": [
            { "data": "Users_ID", "autoWidth": "true" },
            { "data": "Users_Fname", "autoWidth": "true" },
            { "data": "Users_Sname", "autoWidth": "true" },
            { "data": "Users_Email", "autoWidth": "true" },
            { "data": "Users_Usersname", "autoWidth": "true" },
            { "data": "Users_ImagePath", "autoWidth": "true" },
            { "data": "FK_Product_ID", "autoWidth": "true" }
            ]

        })
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried few stackflow troubleshooting but am not getting anywhere

my file structure name are as follows

under the model folder I have EPOSv3DataModel.edmx 
under the home folder I have HomeController.cs file within this

I have the following code :

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to Registration System";
               //EPOSv3Entities1 r = new EPOSv3Entities1();
               //var data = r.tbl_Users.ToList();
               //ViewBag.userdetails = data;
               return View();
            }

        #region Get Users from the database

        public ActionResult GetUsers()
          {
            using (EPOSv3Entities1 entity = new EPOSv3Entities1())
          {
            // get the data order by firstname 
            var users = entity.tbl_Users.OrderBy
            (a => a.Users_Fname).ToList();

            return Json(new { data = users }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }// end of your using statement 
    }

    #endregion
}end of class 
}//end of namespace
```

I was following this video tutorial from: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3pEax-5wXG8&t=1418s)

and the site where this developer has his code is :[ASP.net CRUD DataTable](http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2016/12/crud-operation-using-datatables-aspnet-mvc.html)

Very much appreciate your support the table display but does not load any data 
also when in URL when I enter the https://localhost/portnumber/Home/GetUsers the ajax error disappears but no loading data.

HELP :(

Comment: is your controller action getting called, and do you see any errors on browser's console?

Comment: yes the controller action is getting a called , I am getting a  request return 500 ?

Comment: then there is something wrong on server side code, is action executing completely without any exceptions?

Comment: Yes , the only thing is what cold be wrong on the server side I have attach some picture to aid further

Comment: here is the share link screen shot of the errors https://1drv.ms/f/s!AtdKsCaxzbVuxZw7o49FleTmUzrjCw

Comment: did you checked putting a breakpoint and executing the action code line by line

Comment: are you sure tbl_Users is not empty?

Comment: I have just check and triple check  the table is not empty also from the share link above you will see futher details in the screen shot error7c.png file  about to try putting breakpoint , although I do not get any error or exceptions

Comment: uploaded breakpointErrorD.png file , it seem to find 3 records which is the case but fails at the cshtml side ,

Comment: can you show model of tbl_Users

Comment: I am unable to type the code here so I have uploaded this to the share file area for this tread the link above , model is under file call tbl_Users_Model and also I have included the Code fromt his under tbl_Users_Model.txt file. thanks you for your supports both of you . little or big every little helps

Comment: why is there two tbl_Product ? and tbl_Maintenance ?

Comment: those tables are ment to be futher develop at later stage for the purpose of this exercise all I wanted to achieved was a CRUD  DataTable  hence why I was following the youtube tutorial upon the point 23.45 sec into the video I got stuck as the data never appear in the page.  just perform a nothing test , using the foreach loop not ajax , I was able to see the data shall be uploading this code too in a sec , so proof the link does work its ajax side of things

Comment: I uploaded the page that loads the same data but not in ajax under the folder call AfterLogin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
 using (EPOSv3Entities1 entity = new EPOSv3Entities1())
         {
            entity.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

            // get the data order by firstname 
            var users = entity.tbl_Users.OrderBy
            (a => a.Users_Fname).ToList();

            return Json(new { data = users }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

          }// end of your using statement
```

you are using entity framework generated proxy object which might be causing problems in serializing

Comment: what library do I need to import for context.Configuration ? using ?

Comment: Usman your the man , thanks a billion , May the Almight reward you for this , now for the purpose of learning how did you figure it was proxyCreationEnabled ?  what is it use for ?  thank you once again the above works like a dream.

Comment: ty for your kind words btw in pictures i saw DynamicProxies when i explore it further it was causing problem during conversion to json